# Springs "@MessagingGateway" annotation on external interfaces

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-4

I am about to migrate a project created with an old version of Spring (using XML config) to Spring Boot (using Java config).
The project is using Spring Integration for communication via JMS and AMQP. As far as I understood, I have to replace the

```
<int:gateway id="someID" service-interface="MyMessageGateway" 
 default-request-channel="myRequestChannel" 
 default-reply-channel="myResponseChannel" 
 default-reply-timeout="20000" />
```

with

```
@MessagingGateway(name="someID", defaultRequestChannel = "myRequestChannel",
defaultReplyChannel = "myResponseChannel", defaultReplyTimeout = "20000")
public interface MyMessageGateway{ ...... }
```

My problem is, that the interface, that is in use now, is placed in a library I can't access.

How can I define this Interface as my MessagingGateway?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have to do anything... You can still use the xml configuration, you don't have to migrate everything to java based configuration.

Comment: That's right, for Spring Boot it's not needed.But the department wants to switch to Java-based config. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tested this trick:

```
interface IControlBusGateway {

    void send(String command);
}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "controlBus")
interface ControlBusGateway extends IControlBusGateway {

}

...


@Autowired
private IControlBusGateway controlBus;

...

try {
        this.bridgeFlow2Input.send(message);
        fail("Expected MessageDispatchingException");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        assertThat(e, instanceOf(MessageDeliveryException.class));
        assertThat(e.getCause(), instanceOf(MessageDispatchingException.class));
        assertThat(e.getMessage(), containsString("Dispatcher has no subscribers"));
    }
    this.controlBus.send("@bridge.start()");
    this.bridgeFlow2Input.send(message);
    reply = this.bridgeFlow2Output.receive(5000);
    assertNotNull(reply);
```

In other words you can just `extends` that external interface to your local one. The `GatewayProxyFactoryBean` will do the proxy magic for you underneath.

Also we have this JIRA for similar use-case: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4134

Answer (score 2):

Use a `GatewayProxyFactoryBean`; here's a simple example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So41162166Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So41162166Application.class, args);
        context.getBean(NoAnnotationsAllowed.class).foo("foo");
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public GatewayProxyFactoryBean gateway() {
        GatewayProxyFactoryBean gateway = new GatewayProxyFactoryBean(NoAnnotationsAllowed.class);
        gateway.setDefaultRequestChannel(channel());
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channel")
    public void out(String foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }

    public static interface NoAnnotationsAllowed {

        public void foo(String out);

    }

}
```

Comment: do you have a repo with your all apss that you can shared @gary Rusell , is for leanr how do you scratch the problems....(So41162166Application )

Comment: No; I have written hundreds, maybe over a thousand of these apps during my 10+ years here; it would be a nightmare to keep them current and up to date with CVEs in dependent libraries etc.

Comment: do you have a repo that you like to share...?, I would like to stalk the code ...

Comment: No; as I said; it would need too much maintenance for the hundreds of apps; I don't have time for that. If there is one specific app, then I might be able to add it to a Gist. But, if it's this specific app, @Artem's answer is more elegant. I probably no longer have this one; it was 2 laptops ago.